# How to escape # in javascript to retrive object property

Tags: javascript

i have Javascript object as below.
How can i get value for SERIAL#, like i can retrieve *.INST_ID or *.INSTANCE.
how can i escape # and get the value required.
So far i have tried SERIAL#23% but none helped so far.

```
var t = {"INST_ID":"1","INSTANCE":"xina","SID":"27","SERIAL#":"48810", "PROGRAM":"Perl@app01"}
console.log(kSess.SERIAL%23); gives syntax error
```

I am parsing variable "t"
This data is coming from java code, so there is nothing much i can do to change SERIAL# to something else
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try to retrieve the value like this...

```
t["SERIAL#"];  // will return you the value..
```

Store it somewhere or play with it as you like. :)